# trying to install keras or tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

from keras.layers import Dense
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
from keras.layers import Dense

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

'pip install tensorflow'
Out[78]: 'pip install tensorflow'

Comment: What is the question here? Just posting some error messages without detail or anything else is rude to people that might try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify which base environment (`Anaconda, Pycharm`) you are using to install `tensorflow` or to run python code. If you are using `anaconda` environment, try using below command in `jupyter` notebook to install tensorflow and keras.

```
conda install tensorflow
conda install keras
```

OR

```
!pip install tensorflow
!pip install keras
```

Also you can try fixing this issue using following code:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
```

OR

`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense`

You can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) link to install `tensorflow` in your system.

Comment: Better practice now is to use magics or without the exclamation point and let automagics handle `conda` or `pip` commands when running in a notebook. So `!pip install tensorflow` should be `%pip install tensorflow` inside a cell in the notebook. This new magics insures that the package gets installed into the environment backing the kernel that notebook is using. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magics for pip and conda.